# turbo stream filter frame fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials, hotwire-rails, turbo

To my knowledge I'm passing the variable through, however it keeps throwing an error of `undefined`, digging further it has no `:id`. However the search query does work via a console check and pulls the correct `:id`'s.

**_routine_list:**

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag r do %>  
    <div class="card card--primary">
        <%= link_to routine_path(r), data: { turbo_frame: "_top" } do %>
            <div class="title">
                <%= r.name %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>   
<% end %>
```

**Index:**

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="article center">
      <%= turbo_frame_tag "community_routines", action: "append" do %>
        <% @community_routines.each do |r| %> 
          <%= render 'routine_list', r: r %>
        <% end %>
        <% unless @page.last? %>
          <%= turbo_frame_tag "community_routines", loading: :lazy, src: routines_path(page: @page.next_param) %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**Search controller:**

```
    def search
    @user_r = current_user.id
    if params[:query].present? 
      @routnies = set_page_and_extract_portion_from Routine.where("sport_id = ? ", params[:query])
    else
      @routines = set_page_and_extract_portion_from Routine.all
    end
    respond_to do |f|
      f.turbo_stream do
        render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.update("community_routines",
                                partial: "routines/routine_list", locals: { r: @routines })
      end
    end
  end
```

produces

```
  undefined local variable or method `r'
```

in the routine_list partial. I have no clue what could cause this, I'm passing the variables through `r: r` on the index page.

**UPDATE**

The reason this happens is because the search is is returning a collection relation and is unable to assign to variable.
I'm working on a different filter method and will post the results when confirmed working.

**Edit 2:** I have removed the ***search controller*** and used a filter controller instead for **ALL** my filtering needs. More info in the links provided in the answer I gave below